# Looking for a simple method for displaying tables in android, using App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have been using App Inventor at the MIT website, to make simple calculators for estimating at work. Predetermined formulas are embedded into the apps, that allow for the conversion of user inputted data, into usable information - much quicker and more reliable than doing it manually, with a regular calculator.

What I would like to do next, is make scrollable reference charts from standardized data - like an AWG chart. The columns can be wire gauge, wire diameter, wire weight per foot, etc. The rows would just be the different wire sizes - i.e. 8 gauge, 10 gauge, 12 gauge, etc..

Currently, each "cell" of the chart is an individual text label.

A table arrangement will not work, as it will not scale the individual columns to width of the screen - only to the width of the largest item in each column. So far, individual rows of horizontal arrangements seems to be the only solution - as it will scale and center each column, spacing them evenly across the entire width of the screen - but it is still very time consuming.

Any "better" suggestions on how to get a scrollable table on Android via App Inventor would be much appreciated. I may already be on the right track, and the arduousness of the task ahead is just that intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an excellent solution on YouTube - posted by TutorialMaster on May 10, 2015.

It's not in English, but very easy to follow. All using a csv file and lists.

[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDpub3elQ9c)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I prepared another example for you, which uses 1 horizonal arrangement and 2 labels (1 label for each column) assuming the data is stored in 2 lists
[image]

[image]

Comment: Now this makes perfect sense to me, and even shoes me something that I didn't know you can do in App Inventor - "new line". Unfortunately, it still looks like the end product would be more time consuming, than just making a separate label for each entry.

Each row is a series of about 5 items, and the columns do not change with any kind of set pattern - in some cases, the first column may be repeated a few times - to show information about different versions of the same thing, like a phone book.